# Passing Type Reference Type by Value, but the instace variable is not being reassigned by the method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to replicate an example that shows that when one passes a reference type by value to a method, you can reassign values to instance variables, but not reassign the passed type itself. This is from Andrew Troelsen's book.
Here's the code:

```
 Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle("Numero", 10, 10, 10, 10);
 Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle();
 ChangeRect(r1);
 Console.WriteLine(r1.top);
```

The second argument in the Constructor rectangle is the "top" variable(int).

The ChangeRect method is:

```
static void ChangeRect(Rectangle e)
{
    e.top = 1;
    e = new Rectangle();
}
```

When I run this, I expect the value of the r1.top to change to 1, but the reassignment of the r1 object to a new object with the default constructor to be ignored.
But, when I print the value of r1.top after calling the ChangeRect() method on r1, it keeps showing 10.
What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I suspect the problem is in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Why would you expect the reassignment to be ignored? Also last time I checked you need to pass an object by reference not by value if you want to change it.

Comment: What is `Rectangle`?  How is that defined?

Comment: @VTodorov, with reference types you don't pass the object, you pass the reference/pointer. This pointer, when passed by value, will allow you to change the object that is referenced. When passed by ref you can change what object in memory the pointer points to.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thank you for your comment! This article explains it pretty well too: http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rectangle` is a `struct` and therefore a value type. If you want to modify it and also have a new instance, add `ref` to the parameter and set the return type;

```
static Rectangle ChangeRect(ref Rectangle e)
{
    e.top = 1;
    return new Rectangle();
}
```

Then when calling it, you'd have;

```
Rectangle newRect = ChangeRect(ref r1);
```

I'd point out though that modifying the value being passed in and returning a new instance is odd behaviour for a method called `ChangeRect`. Perhaps consider renaming it to `SetTopAndGetNew()` or separating out the two operations.

Comment: The first part is correct, but passing `ref` would defeat the purpose of showing the behavior explained in the first question sentence.

Comment: "Rectangle is a struct" - which `Rectangle` type are you assuming this is? (Bear in mind that wherever it comes from, it has to have an accessible `top` field or property, not `Top` - and a constructor accepting a string as a first parameter.)

Comment: Thank you DiskJunky, this is what I was missing. I changed the Rectangle type to a Class, instead and it worked. As it turns out, I wasn't passing a Reference Type as value and that was the problem, as you pointed out. But how did you know it was a struct? I didn't specify this on the question. As Jon Skeet correctly suspected, the problem was in code I wasn't showing indeed.

Comment: @NeoTrader, you stated "on r1, it keeps showing 10". If it was a reference type then it would have changed

Comment: @JonSkeet, corrected casing, you're right, the structure is custom and the answer should reflect that.

Comment: Ideally, the question should be fixed first - currently it's really not helpful to anyone. To be honest, I think the question should probably be deleted, given that as soon as the `Rectangle` struct is posted, it will be self-contradictory.